Is the non dual realisation same as the experience we gain after taking psychedelic drugs?
Psychedelic drugs are those drugs after intaking them can distort the sense of reality within minutes. Some of the psychedelic drugs are Dimethyltryptamine and magic mushroom. After consuming them, we can experience the below multiple dimensional altered state of consciousness:

Blissful state
Anxious Ego Dissolution
Experience of unity
Insightfulness and
Disembodiment.

Now blissful state is nothing but Aananda state of Vedantic realisation, anxious ego dissolution is death of ahamkara, experience of unity is the experience of samadhi, insightfulness is deeper understanding of reality and disembodiment means separated from the bodily state or material existence.
So,do those who claimed Advaitic realisation merely had the psychedelic drugs experience or is the Advaitic non dual realisation different from psychedelic experience in any manner?

@PrasannaR Effects of drugs last longer for few hours only. But with what I heard is that non dual reality once realised is permanent. In this way one cannot compare realisation with drug effects. Am I right?

See one thing im clear self realization experience whether is im i eligible to comment,  No, because i didnt have the experience neither do i have psychalidic drugs experience, so i cannot comment on neither of them my apologies for earlier comment saying similar based on the words given by drug additics, see this will become effictive selling point for this addictis never encourage them. cigarrate is not good even consumed in small quantities. but comes with attractive packages similar case for drugs

Based of Aghora series, these drugs are used to prevent distraction of mind  in sadhana. Astral entities will first screw ur mind.  caveat is  the moment they control you, you are done.

They are not the same.
Non-dual realisation or self-realisation is persistent knowledge (jnana) of being, consciousness and bliss (satchitanana). Once realised it doesn't end and it is recognised it has no beginning. Whereas intoxication has a beginning and an end in time.
The nature of Self (Atma) is satchitananda (being, consciousness and bliss, as you say). These are persistent, non changing attributes of Atma and Brahman. They are timeless and beyond the birth and death of the material world. Consequently they are ever present. That which conceals or distracts from that realisation of Atma is essentially the material world; the world of the mind, thoughts and senses.
Psychedelic drugs cause a temporary stimulation of the mind which is experienced as being of the mind, thoughts and senses. In other words, psychedelic drugs are material. They have a start and end in time. The drug experience happens and is known to you; as consciousness (chit), but they are not persistent and not what one seeks.
It could be said that the bliss experienced through drugs is similar to the bliss (ananda) of atmajnana (self-realisation). However if one hasn't recognised the ananda of Atma first, then the seeker of Advaita may not be able to identify the bliss when sober or know if the bliss of drugs is the bliss she or he seeks. The ignorance (Avidya) persists, like a murky hangover that can't be shaken loose.
In contrast a gnani or the self-realised will recognise the very same ananda in wakefulness and sleep, as well as under the influence of drugs. This is because the persistent nature of ananda is realised and recognised as non dependent and distinct from all mental states and experiences. It simply is you, no matter what is going on to you.
The bliss is not something new or different to that which is at hand to a seeker now. It is rather the recognition of satchitananda as your eternal self, through correct intuitive discrimination, that is called non-dual realisation. It is at hand now and here for all. Hence the two are different.
